# getting started with Office Outlook add-in?

Tags: outlook-addin

I'm about to work on some Outlook add-ins.  It's been years since I did this; and probably several object model revisions!

Can anyone recommend some references to help get me started: blogs, sites, books??

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your budget can afford it (ie. the product is making money), I would highly recommend [Add-in Express](http://www.add-in-express.com/). Lots of samples, documentation, and support -- but requires using their tooling. (It makes Outlook ever so slightly-less of a PITA to deal with.)

However, if you prefer to stick with a (free with VS) Microsoft solution -- it works fairly well, but is missing some "niceties" -- then check out the [VSTO on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/default) page as a first stop an follow the links out. There are also some good sample projects, templates, and VSTO tools on [codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=vsto).

Happy coding.

**Edit:** I guess I must be bored :-) Here are some selected links that I found helpful. some of these are very specific/advanced, and some are more general. The arrangement is in no particular order.

1. [MSDN Outlook 2010 Top-Level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff458122.aspx). Links to documentation (MAPI, PIAs) etc.
2. [SGriffin's MAPI Internals](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephen_griffin/). *Lots* of details wrt MAPI. Generally on low-level access but also a good source to find out about changes, new documentation or tools, etc. He could probably rewrite MAPI from memory.
3. [MFCMAPI Program & Source](http://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/) Invaluable tool for inspecting MAPI folders, properties, and whatnot. Is Microsofts "reference example" for most "How do I do x in MAPI?".
4. [OutlookSpy Program](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/). This isn't free, but there is a trial. It may or may not work better than MFCMAPI for particular needs. This was written by the author of [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/), a supplement/replacement for the PIA OOM access. Dimastr has also answered a number of (advanced) Outlook/MAPI forum posts online -- always a good person to look out for.
5. [Outlook 2010 Messaging API (MAPI) Code Samples](http://ol2010mapisamples.codeplex.com/) - Covers basic (wrapper) implementations of the providers (address/store/transport). All native C++.
6. [OutlookCode.com](http://www.outlookcode.com/) Site promotes some Outlook books by Sue Mosher. I can't vouch for the books, but the site is a mixed-blessing with some good links, some useful advice, and some downright ugly code :-) Also has a forum.

Comment: Is Add-in Express OK for a commercial product?  I read that it had its own interop assemblies -- more stuff to install.

Comment: @Chris I actually only use the PIAs. The ADX interops try to be more supportive of all the versions ("version neutral") but are missing some newer operations supported by the OL2007/2010 PIAs (I only target 2007/2010 so the ADX interops are not advantageous for me). The PIAs cover *most* cases of dealing with the OOM, but hide some of the underlying MAPI of course :-/ Make sure to ComRefRelease as appropriate (very important for items!) -- but it's trial and error determining "ownership" as this is not documented (at all!). I guess VB6 was better for some things ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio Tools for Office in VS2010 has come a *long* way. I used to make (and sell) an Outlook add-in for Tablet PC's and it was very complicated back then. A properly designed add-in in .NET would need to set up a separate AppDomain to avoid stomping on other add-ins and implement all kinds of workarounds to avoid leaving orphaned Outlook processes when the main window closed.

VSTO does all this "out of the box" now.

[Outlook Solutions in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386094.aspx)

Comment: I'm glad to hear the programming environment has improved.  I had done some VBA and COM stuff against Word in the 90's.  Working with Outlook will be interesting.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget this MSDN forum as a great resource:

Outlook for Developers Forum: 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/outlookdev/threads

BTW, @pst: you can still use late-binding to work with the newer Object Models within a version neutral ADX project.

@Josh: VSTO already loads each add-in into it's own AppDomain

@everyone: I work for ADX, feel free to ping me for any questions.