# integrate outlook with JS web app

Tags: javascript, api, outlook

I have a stand alone JS web application that I need to connect to Outlook and retrieve outlook objects via APIs, I'm not sure which API should I choose (javascriptAPI, PIA or MAPI).

Has anyone done something like this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm no expert but if your app is JS based, and there is a JS based API, I'd assume that'd be a good one to start with.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, but isn't JavaScriptAPI for mail apps only?

Answer (score 1):

That actually depends heavily on your use case and your willingness to dive into stuff.

First off, I can strongly recommend to have a look at the comparison page Microsoft put up:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900714.aspx

The most powerful option is by any means the option to do a native addin using C++ and accessing MAPI directly. However this can get very complex and if you are not into native coding, I would advise against this. Some resources to get started:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941475(v=office.14).aspx

The next best option would be do develop a managed VSTO addin using C# or similar .NET languages (PIA). This is much easier, but I would also use this only in combination with the excellent Redemption Library (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm). It makes your life much easier, especially when developing for multiple Outlook versions.

The JS API provided by Microsoft is very limited at the moment sadly and only does allow you to access things on an item level. This could be enough for your use case, but if you plan synchronization use cases that may not be enough.

Our company is also working on building an more rich JS API on top of Outlook. If you are interested you can check it out here: http://api.yasoon.com. We are also not as feature rich as the managed API and only in beta at the moment, so you may want to clarify your exact requirements first. In general, the managed API using C# is probably the best option if you need full control.

This other StackOverflow thread also contains a lot of information on this topic:
[getting started with Office Outlook add-in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590557/getting-started-with-office-outlook-add-in)

Answer (score 0):

If you guys are using outlook.com, you can use the [outlook.com API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826535.aspx).

You need to [authenticate using OAuth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440163.aspx) and then you can perform API calls to read and write contacts. For example, this is from the [MS docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826527.aspx) about reading/writing contacts:

```
function readContact_onClick() {
    WL.login({
        scope: "wl.basic"
    }).then(
        function (response) {
            WL.api({
                path: "contact.83960a61000000000000000000000000",
                method: "GET"
            }).then(
                function (response) {
                    document.getElementById("resultDiv").innerHTML =
                        "ID: " + response.id +
                        "<br/>Name: " + response.first_name +
                        " " + response.last_name;
                },
                function (responseFailed) {
                    document.getElementById("infoArea").innerText =
                        "Error calling API: " + responseFailed.error.message;
                }
            );
        },
        function (responseFailed) {
            document.getElementById("infoArea").innerText =
                "Error signing in: " + responseFailed.error_description;
        }
    );
}
```